# Laravel ORM Detail -> Master History

Tags: laravel, orm

I want to orderby orderMaster.date 'desc', but it no luck, even I added the function ($query) { $query->orderBy('date', 'desc'); } inside the "with", but it can show correctly.

```
OrderDetail::with('orderMaster', 'item')->get(),
```

The relations of the these tables
orderMaster ->(one to many) orderDetail ->(one to one) Item

I want to show the items purchase histories order by orderMaster.date desc in current order.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In your orderMaster relation you could simply do something like this:

```
$this->hasMany('SomeClass')->orderBy('date', 'desc');
```

Comment: Sorry, Because I am using OrderDetail::with('orderMaster'),
so even I added this inside orderMaster Model orderBy, it can't help.